# Rails Routes only link_to only generating get requests rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rubymine

I am running rails 5.0.2 and have been following along with https://gorails.com/episodes/liking-posts?autoplay=1 to add a like button on my products show page.

I cannot for the life of me work out why I keep hitting the error

No route matches [GET] "/products/7199/like"

the repo for the tutorial is here https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/gorails-24-liking-posts/blob/master/app/views/posts/_likes.html.erb

As per the tutorial, I have a a routes.rb like so, I added only [:create, :destroy] during testing to try to get the post request. I even tested without the member do.

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "pages#home"

  devise_for    :users,
              :path => '',
              :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
              :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks',
                               :registrations => 'registrations'
              }

  resources :users, only: [:show]
  resources :vendors, only: [:show]
  resources :brands, only: [:show]
  resources :products do
    resource :like, only: [:create,:destroy], module: :products
    member do
      get :toggle_status
    end
  end

  resources :pages
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

end
```

my likes.rb model is

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

my likes_controller is nested in products. I added the @product.id as I am using friendly_id, and the tutorial uses the product id.

```
class Products::LikesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_product

  def create
    @product.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).create!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @product.id}
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @product.id }
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end
end
```

My Buttons are on my products show page( I did have them in a partial(_likes.html.erb) but moved them back for testing)

```
<div id="product_<%= @product.id %>_likes" class="col-md-6">
        <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.likes?(@product) %>
            <%= link_to 'Unlike', product_like_path(@product.id), method: :delete, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' %>
        <%- else -%>
            <%= link_to 'Like', product_like_path(@product.id), method: :post, remote: true, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

and a create.js.erb and a destroy.js.erb have been created in views/products/likes as follows

create

```
$('#product_<%= @product.id %>_likes').html("<%=j render partial: 'products/likes', locals: {product: @product} %>");
```

destroy

```
$('#product_<%= @product.id %>_likes').html("<%=j render partial: 'products/likes', locals: {product: @product} %>");
```

initially I thought I had a turbolinks issue( which I still may) but noticed that I am not hitting the Post, despite my code. here is the rake

```
ake routes | grep like
                product_like DELETE   /products/:product_id/like(.:format)  products/likes#destroy
                             POST     /products/:product_id/like(.:format)  products/likes#create
```

my application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
// jquery_ujs allows us to use 'data-remote',
// 'data-type', and 'data-method' attributes
//
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require html.sortable
//= require turbolinks
//= require turbolinks-compatibility
//= require_tree .

$.turbo.use('turbolinks:load', 'turbolinks:request-start');

var resetForms = function () {
    // this depends on your use
    // this is for foundation 6's abide
    $('form').each(function () {
        $(this).foundation('destroy');
    });
};

document.addEventListener("turbolinks:before-cache", function() {
    resetForms();
});
```

and I have the following dependency files in my javascript folder

```
application.coffee
cable.js
search.js
turbolinks-compatibility.coffee
search.coffee
loading.js
favorite_products.coffee
```

Any guidance you can give me to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have jquery-ujs in your application.js file like he does : https://github.com/gorails-screencasts/gorails-24-liking-posts/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/application.js?

Comment: Yes make sure `jquery_ujs` is required in your `application.js`

Comment: Hi @RyanDrost, I have updated to show the file

Comment: Hi @JCorcuera I have updated to show the application.js file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of pulling my hair out, I found that the original developer had added an application.coffee file that seemed to only handle the social share side of things.

I removed the offending file. and all else worked. Including the turbolinks issue. So essentially above is what you would need to add a like system to your products model.